# How to import obj-c static const in swift xctest

Tags: swift, objective-c, xctest

I have a xcode project containing both obj-c and swift code. Test codes are written in swift.  I need to import static const declared in Obj-c .m file into xctest.

```
// Book.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Book.h"

static NSString * const MyValue = @"my_value"; // I need to refer this in swift test code

@implementation Book

@synthesize bookId;

- (void)someMethod {
}

@end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-do-i-call-objective-c-code-from-swift?rq=1 This may help you

Comment: If you share a specific code example, folks can share specific answers.